# DB Design Pattern - Many to many classification / categorised tagging

Tags: sql-server, database, design-patterns, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I have an existing database design that stores Job Vacancies.

The "Vacancy" table has a number of fixed fields across all clients, such as "Title", "Description", "Salary range".

There is an EAV design for "Custom" fields that the Clients can setup themselves, such as, "Manager Name", "Working Hours". The field names are stored in a "ClientText" table and the data stored in a "VacancyClientText" table with VacancyId, ClientTextId and Value.

Lastly there is a many to many EAV design for custom tagging / categorising the vacancies with things such as Locations/Offices the vacancy is in, a list of skills required. This is stored as a "ClientCategory" table listing the types of tag, "Locations, Skills", a "ClientCategoryItem" table listing the valid values for each Category, e.g., "London,Paris,New York,Rome", "C#,VB,PHP,Python". Finally there is a "VacancyClientCategoryItem" table with VacancyId and ClientCategoryItemId for each of the selected items for the vacancy.

There are no limits to the number of custom fields or custom categories that the client can add.

---

I am now designing a new system that is very similar to the existing system, however, I have the ability to restrict the number of custom fields a Client can have and it's being built from scratch so I have no legacy issues to deal with.

For the Custom Fields my solution is simple, I have 5 additional columns on the Vacancy Table called CustomField1-5. This removes one of the EAV designs.

It is with the tagging / categorising design that I am struggling. If I limit a client to having 5 categories / types of tag. Should I create 5 tables listing the possible values "CustomCategoryItems1-5" and then an additional 5 many to many tables "VacancyCustomCategoryItem1-5"

This would result in 10 tables performing the same storage as the three tables in the existing system.

Also, should (heaven forbid) the requirements change in that I need 6 custom categories rather than 5 then this will result in a lot of code change.

---

Therefore, can anyone suggest any DB Design Patterns that would be more suitable to storing such data. I'm happy to stick with the EAV approach, however, the existing system has come across all the usual performance issues and complex queries associated with such a design.

Any advice / suggestions are much appreciated.

The DBMS system used is SQL Server 2005, however, 2008 is an option if required for any particular pattern.

Comment: If I could put the problem into a small line then I probably wouldn't have a problem in the first place. As the question is a design question then unfortunately the only way to get any advice is to detail as much information about the requirement as possible.

Comment: This question here shows the performance issues that I get when writing a query to return the results of such a many to many EAV pattern. The responses here were "Don't do it." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386577/sql-server-query-performance-clustered-index-seek

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using an XML column? You can enforce all your constraints declaratively through XSL.

Instead of EAV, have a single column with XML data validated by a schema (or a collection of schemas).

Comment: I am considering XML. I have used it for a number of non schema bound situations but have never gone so far as to use it heavily as an alternative to EAV. I will do some investigation on this and see how it "feels".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [**at this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932322/how-to-design-a-schema-where-the-columns-of-a-table-are-not-fixed/2932403#2932403) question/answer; describes the observation pattern.
It uses five tables and can be implemented in a "standard" RDBMS -- Sql Server 2005 will do.
No limit on number of custom properties (observations) that an entity can have.

**EDIT**

If tags (categories) are needed for properties, take a look **[at this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712622/how-to-setup-organization-specific-data-elements-about-shared-items/1716026#1716026)**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the custom fields in a key-value table?

```
| vacancy ID | CustomFieldType | CustomFieldValue |
```

Then have auxillary tables listing possible values per type (1 table) and may be possible types per vacancy type (it seems to be the original ClientCategory)

Comment: That is the current EAV approach on the custom one to one fields. I can do away with the EAV approach by making them fixed columns that will help with simplicity and performance. However it is the many to many fields that I am looking for options for.

Comment: @Robin - Sorry, I find this approach to be the best both design wise and perfrmance wise... your choice of course :)

Comment: This question here shows the performance issues that I get when writing a query to return the results of such a many to many EAV pattern. The responses here were "Don't do it." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386577/sql-server-query-performance-clustered-index-seek